# zeromq push/pull architecture -high water mark

Tags: message-queue, zeromq, publish-subscribe

Question about zeromq push-pull architecture:

how zeromq buffers messages both at sender and receiver end.

what will happen if in the following cases:

1.The main memory of system goes low before reaching the high watermark limit.

2. if high watermark limit is reached (e.g in 1000 messages)
   then what will happen? will it maintain a queue for the blocked messages as well ?

3.what if zeromq enters the exceptional state and did not get back for hours?

Thanks